# Factory creating multiple models with different number of relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-factory

I'm using the following code to create 20 posts, each of which has 3 comments.

```php
Post::factory()
    ->times(20)
    ->has(Comment::factory()->times(3))
    ->create()
```

Instead I'd like to create 20 posts, each of which has a random number of comments (e.g. post 1 has 2 comments, post 2 has 4 comments, etc.)

This did not work, each post had the same (random) number of comments.

```php
Post::factory()
    ->times(20)
    ->has(Comment::factory()->times(rand(1, 5)))
    ->create()
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: make it with an variable `$times = rand(1,5);` see the answear below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to have a dynamic number of related models per model if you are using `->times` as far as I know. You can instead try:

```
collect(range(0,19))
   ->each(function () {
       Post::factory()
          ->has(Comment::factory()->times(rand(1,5)))
          ->create();
});
```

This should create 20 posts one by one with a random number of comments on each. It may be a bit slower but probably not by much

Comment: Thanks apokryfos. Works great.

Comment: Super cool! Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a factory method to do this. Add a method to your `Post` factory like this:

```php
<?php
namespace Database\Factories\App;

use App\Comment;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            // ...
        ];
    }

    public function addComments(int $count = null): self
    {
        $count = $count ?? rand(1, 5);
    
        return $this->afterCreating(
            fn (Post $post) => Comment::factory()->count($count)->for($post)->create()
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your test, you can simply call it like this:

```php
Post::factory()->count(20)->addComments()->create();
```

Comment: Thanks miken32.

Comment: No problem, seems like a more elegant solution and easier to tell what's happening at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** That should work:
Inspired by apokryfos. If that not work, that will:

```
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++)
{
    $times = rand(1,5);
    Post::factory()
     ->has(Comment::factory()->times($times))
     ->create();
}
```

Comment: ok. Maybe try with  count($times) `->has(Comment::factory()->count($times))`. If that doesn't work, it will be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Tanks Maik Lowrey. Works well.